# How to interactive edit vector in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I want to create a vector in R shiny, to add element and show the result in ui.R.

But seems inside server.R, it will overwrite the old element in the vector, instead append the vector.

Here is my code

ui.R

```
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("actionButton test"),
  sidebarPanel(
    textInput("symb", "Symbol", "SPY"),
    br(),
    actionButton("addButton", "Add"),
    p("Click the button to update the value displayed in the main panel.")
  ),
  mainPanel(
    verbatimTextOutput("nText")
  )
))
```

server.R

```
equity_list = c("ACN")
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  output$nText <- renderText({
    # Take a dependency on input$goButton
    input$goButton

    # Use isolate() to avoid dependency on input$n
    isolate(input$symb)

    equit_list <<- append(equity_list, input$symb)
  })  
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi you have two problems in your app :

1. you do not use the correct id of `actionButton` in `server.R`
2. you have to overwrite `equity_list` when you append a new element

Try this :

```
library(shiny)
runApp(list(
  ui = pageWithSidebar(
    headerPanel("actionButton test"),
    sidebarPanel(
      textInput("symb", "Symbol", "SPY"),
      br(),
      actionButton("addButton", "Add"),
      p("Click the button to update the value displayed in the main panel.")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      verbatimTextOutput("nText")
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    equity_list = c("ACN")
    output$nText <- renderText({
      input$addButton
      isolate({
        equity_list <<- append(equity_list, input$symb)
      })
    })  
  }
))
```

EDIT : 2 buttons it's not easy. You can try the app below, the hic is that you have to clic "add" after "delete". I've changed `textInput` for `selectizeInput`, it's more flexible :

```
library(shiny)
runApp(list(
  ui = pageWithSidebar(
    headerPanel("actionButton test"),
    sidebarPanel(
      selectizeInput(inputId = "symb", label = "Symbol", selected = "SPY", choices = "SPY", multiple = TRUE, options = list(create = TRUE)),
      br(),
      actionButton("addButton", "Add"),
      p("Click the button to update the value displayed in the main panel."),
      actionButton("deleteButton", "Delete")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      verbatimTextOutput("nText")
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    equity_list = c("ACN")

    equity_rea <- reactive({
      equity_list <- append(equity_list, input$symb)
    })

observe({
  input$deleteButton
  updateSelectizeInput(session = session, inputId = "symb", selected = "SPY")
})

output$nText <- renderText({
  # with add button
  input$addButton | input$deleteButton
  isolate(equity_rea())
  # without add button
  #equity_rea()
})
```

}
))

Comment: Hello Vcitorp, Another question, if I want to add a delete button, how to do? Sorry I am pretty new in Shiny.

Comment: I add another example with an other way to do the same thing and a delete button, but it do not work properly.

Comment: Seems shiny can only has one dependence, add or delete are two, they conflict with each other.